# how can i make web gis application using geoserver,postgresql,arcgis and c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, arcgis, geoserver

I am using open geo suite to develop webgis application but it is difficult for me to make front end because i am more familiar with .net framework. Can anyone please help me to find the solution? I will be thankful. So can I make a web gis application using c#.net, geoserver, arcgis and postgresql? Is there any way to work with open geo suite and C#.net together to build this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not suppose to answer this. But the simple answer is yes. If you are looking for create webgis application in C#, there may be less solutions comparing to other path.

When you look at the techniques, postgres is the database engine works with most of the GIS servers. Geoserver/arcgis are popular gis server solutions. .Net framework certainly is used in GIS too. Without defining your actual application goal, simply put several techniques together does not make much sense to me.

My suggestion would be 1) Define the problem you gonna solve/ application used for. 2) Basic architect design 3)Design workflow

After that you can ask here with those information to see if a certain part of workflow doable or there is any alternative solution, i am pretty sure more people will be willing to answer your questions that way.

Comment: can you please help me regarding this code i want to shorw info from the geoserver data where wardboundary is a .shp file contains data. so can you please tell me how to show it on the map in a pop up window?? Here is the following code:

Comment: i did this using mvc4, geoserver and postgis.

Comment: I can not see the code. But based on what your comment. I am guessing you are going to have a .Net desktop application to show your data from a shape file. If so, there first step is to load shapefile to postgis. Then in geoserver, make the connection to postgis and publish the data as a service. Then in your desktop application, parse the get map request to service call. That is basically how you do this typically. It is hard to bring details or code. But you based on these steps i think you could probably find a path to what you want. Please post new question for more people to get involved